# Unknown for me error with requests in Python

Tags: python, python-requests

```
30
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Code fs\gui.py", line 2, in <module>     
    import requests
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 118, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 27, in <module>
    from ._internal_utils import to_native_string
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\_internal_utils.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .compat import is_py2, builtin_str, str
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\compat.py", line 29, in <module>
    import simplejson as json
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\simplejson\__init__.py", line 130, in <module>
    from decimal import Decimal
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\decimal.py", line 3, in <module>
    from _decimal import *
AttributeError: module 'numbers' has no attribute 'Number'
```

When I try to run my code this error appears and I don't know why.
If I didn't provide enough details please say what I need to add. Thanks in advance

This is the all of the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import requests
import json

def jprint(obj):
    text = json.dumps(obj, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    print(text)


window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("900x550")
window.title("Yo mama")
window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

def yomama():
    response = requests.get("https://api.yomomma.info/")
    jprint(response.json())
    
    
        
     

welcome_label = tk.Label(window,
                         text="Welcome! Click the button to get a extreamly funny yo mama joke",
                         font=("Helvetica", 15))
welcome_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="N", padx=20, pady=10)

button = tk.Button(text="Get spicy yo mama joke", command=yomama)
button.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="WE", padx=10, pady=10)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    window.mainloop()
```

⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀                                ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: Do you have another file in the same directory called `numbers.py`?

Comment: you're sharing only traceback, please share your code, without this the question is vague.

Comment: @Rohithaditya you can call what the offending code is from the first line of the traceback: `import requests`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It worked. Using Python 3.12.0 and Windows 10.